# trouble with using transform origin on keyframe css

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a `<div class="sphere" />` that I want to move in the shape of infinity symbol. So I thought the answer should be to fix `transform-origin` to `left`, from 0 to 50%, make it do a full rotation, then change `transform-origin` to `right`, and from 50.01% to 100% make it do a full rotation again and reset tranform origin like so

```css
.sphere {
        position: absolute;
        width: var(--sphere-dim);
        height: var(--sphere-dim);
        background: rgb(183, 162, 159);
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 40%;
        left: 40%;
        transform-origin: left;
        /* transition: all 1.5s; */
        /* animation-fill-mode: forwards; */
        animation: infinityWobble 5s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes infinityWobble {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        50% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
        50.01% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform-origin: right;
        }
        99% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
        100% {
            transform-origin: left;
        }
    }
```

https://codepen.io/meherwan-singh-gill/pen/ExOKxmv

^ this is the result

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct codepen?

Comment: @Coolis lmao mb, just edited added the correct link

Comment: I think the rotate animation is not visible because your element is a circle, so the rotate property of the element will not be visible.

Comment: You can't do it by rotating the circle round a point that is within the circle itself - it won't make a sweeping arc.

Comment: @Coolis  
but if you set transform-origin: , you should be able to do this , as an example, here is another code pen https://codepen.io/meherwan-singh-gill/pen/dyQMyJq .
If you see here, i have comprised a wobble with wobbleleft and wobbleright and used JS to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a detailed article on how to create such an animation (and more): https://css-tricks.com/advanced-css-animation-using-cubic-bezier/

Here is the first code from the article:

```css
.ball {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:radial-gradient(at 30% 30%,#0000,#000a) red;
  left: var(--x);
  top: var(--y);
  animation: x 1s, y 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.5, -800, .5, 800);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes x {
  to {
    left: calc(var(--x) + 1px);
  }
}

@keyframes y {
  to {
    top: calc(var(--y) + 0.3px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball" style="--x:300px;--y:100px;"></div>
```

Another version with transform for better performance

```css
.ball {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:radial-gradient(at 30% 30%,#0000,#000a) red;
  left: 300px;
  top: 100px;
  animation: x 1s, y 0.5s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.5, -800, .5, 800);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes x {
  to {
    translate: 1px 0;
  }
}

@keyframes y {
  to {
    transform: translatey(0.3px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: Holy, that's smooth. Nice!

Comment: AMazing, i love the math bit there aswell.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned the `rotate` animation will be not visible because the element you are rotating is a circle. So in this case you either need to play with `transformX` and `transformY`, or another approach will be changing the `top` and `left` position of the element. Here is an example. Hope it helps a bit :)

```css
.container
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.sphere
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%; 
    left:1%;
    
   animation: infinity 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes infinity
{
     6.25%  {top: 21%; left:3%}
    12.5%  {top: 7%; left:11%;}
    18.75%  {top: 12%; left:25%;}
    25% {top: 48%; left:47%;}
    
    31.25%  {top: 84%;  left:71%;}
    37.5% {top: 91%; left: 82%}
    43.75% {top: 73%; left: 92%;}
    50% { top: 47%; left: 94%;}
    
    56.25% {top: 23%; left: 92%;}
    62.5% {top: 6%; left: 82%;}
    68.75% {top: 12%; left: 70%;}
    75% { top: 48%; left:47%; }
    
    81.25% { top: 73%; left: 33%;}
    87.5% { top: 89%; left: 19%;}
    93.75% { top: 84%; left: 7%; } 
    100% { top: 48%;  left:1%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sphere"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, thank you.
I was changing that initially but then i thought that rotation would be a more elegant solution. I still dont understand why transform-origin doesnt work, since if. you change the transform origin, it means that the axis of rotation isnt the centre anymore, hence there wont be symmetry. So if  make transform-origin left, it will rotate from the circumference. 
Thank you for your solution though.

Comment: The problem was not the switching of the axis. Changing the `transform-origin` is a correct approach but in that case you will need to adjust accordingly `top` and `left`. The problem on your question was the `transform: rotate()` property. This property just rotates the element but does not move it.

Comment: I am so sorry, do bear with me, for I seem to have some trouble here
if you look at this new code pen  codepen.io/meherwan-singh-gill/pen/dyQMyJq and you click on the sphere it does an almost infinity like shape. But here I am not changing transform origin within the keyframe but outside it by adding and removing class via js. So in the first 2 seconds, it does a full rotation on the left, then that class is removed, and another class is added where it does a rotation on the right, which I thought should be same as combining it in one keyframe. 50% left and 50% right.